# Page content included in Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First Output : https://ibb.co/k2RJ1m6

What i need to achieve : https://ibb.co/86nhB6m

The Page Content is the X Mark and the toolbar. But instead of being outside like the 2nd Image, it is getting included inside the Sidebar. Here's the Code

```
<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

      <nav id="sidebar">
        <!-- <script src="C-NavigationBar.js"></script> -->
      </nav>

      <div id="content">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
           <div class="container-fluid">
              <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="navbar-btn">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
              </button>
           </div>
         </nav>
       </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Please make it so that your screenshot is only showing the relative parts. It might not be really interesting to know the whereabouts of your CarWash

Comment: It is the whole page. Content is shown in the Nav Bar @DannyvanHolten

Comment: I have literally just posted the code which is necessary. how is it long? @Paulie_D

Comment: There is no CSS and it does not demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make style for your output so when you add the style in your code it will work like your second image.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
  #sidebar{
    background-color:#000;
    width:230px;
    height:100vh;
    float:left;
  }
  #content{
    float:left;
    width:calc(100% - 230px);
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .navbar-btn span:first-child {
    width: 26px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.navbar-btn span:last-child {
    width: 26px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.navbar-btn {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
}
  </style>
```